# Share session over subdomain work with IE but not with Firefox

Tags: asp.net, subdomain

I have an issue with sharing session over subdomains.
I have an application wich can be access by

- http://myapplication.com
- http://customer1.myapplication.com
- http://customer2.myapplication.com

I set up my web.config file like this :

```
<httpCookies domain=".myapplication.com"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="index.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="60000" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain=".myapplication.com"/>
</authentication>
```

"enableCrossAppRedirects" can be configured to true or false, nothing change.

In IE, when I switch from on subdomain to another, I always use the same session. But with Firefox, each time, I change subdomain, a new session is created for each.

I read lot of article on google but nothing work. I don't understand why Firefox is different

This is a simple aspx code page to test by yourself

```
<%@ Import NameSpace="System" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Linq" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Collections" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.Security" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Reflection" %>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web.SessionState" %>
<script language="c#" runat="server">

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Log("<b>Refresh twice to see result after switch to another subdomain</b>");
if (Session["CREATION"] == null)
{
string navigateur = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToString    ();
if (navigateur.ToUpper().Contains("FIREFOX"))
{
navigateur = "Firefox";
}
else if (navigateur.ToUpper().Contains("MSIE"))
{
navigateur = "Internet Explorer";
}

Session["CREATION"] = "Session create at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss") + " by "     +      navigateur;  
}
Session["HOST"] = Request.Headers["HOST"];
Session["SESSIONID"] = Session.SessionID;
CheckSession();
}
private void Log(string text)
{
Label1.Text += text + "<br/>";
}
public void CheckSession()
{
object obj = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("CacheInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);   
object[] obj2 = (object[])obj.GetType().GetField("_caches", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
for (int i = 0; i < obj2.Length; i++)
{
Hashtable c2 = (Hashtable)obj2[i].GetType().GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj2[i]);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in c2)
{

object o1 = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Value", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(entry.Value, null);
if (o1.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionState")
{
Log("<hr/>");
SessionStateItemCollection sess = (SessionStateItemCollection)o1.GetType().GetField("_sessionItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(o1);                
if (sess != null)
{
foreach (string key in sess.Keys)
{
Label1.Text += key + " = " + sess[key] + "<br>";
}

}
}
}
}

}
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope somebody could help me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first dot, from the domain, in the settings. And your code will be as:

```
<httpCookies domain="myapplication.com"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="index.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="60000" 
      enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="myapplication.com"/>
</authentication>
```

Using this dot, you do not let the subdomain to read the cookie and make a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.

It's better, I can switch between subdomain and the same session is use each time. But if I switch to http://myapplication.com (without subdomain) from a subdomain, a new session is created with Firefox but not with IE. Why ?

Regards

Comment: @seb49 Maybe you need to clear the cookies (not all, only for this domain) ? because as you work on development some cookies stay and can not be overwriten. Clear them and test it again